# SourcePollingChannelAdapter with Transaction

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-transactions

I would like to use a SourcePollingChannelAdapter with a transaction propagation REQUIRED when the polling is realized, to rollback all operations if an error is occured. The method setTransactionSynchronizationFactory is not commented...
Thanks a lot for your help !

In XML I can do :

```
<int:poller fixed-rate="5000">
  <int:transactional transaction-manager="transactionManager" propagation="REQUIRED" />
</int:poller>
```

I would like to use a transaction like this programmatically with a SourcePollingChannelAdapter and a PeriodicTrigger, but I don't know how.

I have this :

```
SourcePollingChannelAdapter adapter = new SourcePollingChannelAdapter();
adapter.setSource(source);
adapter.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
adapter.setOutputChannel(channel);
adapter.setBeanFactory(ctx);
adapter.start();
```

When the bean source is called, an element in database are deleted, a message is created and sent in outputchannel; but if i have an error in the flow after the ouputchannel i would like database restored and element came back ... a simple transaction in fact with propagation. I don't understand how do that.

The ouputchannel is :

```
<int:channel id="channel" >
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>
<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="channel"
    url="http://localhost:8081/icopitole-ws/baseactive" http-method="GET"
    reply-channel="reresponseVersionChannel" expected-response-type="java.lang.String"  />
```

When the URL doesn't respond, an exception is thrown but no Rollback is executed, although I have add a DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory and TransactionInterceptor like you said :(

Comment: Sorry, not enough info. `poller` can be marked with `<transactional synchronization-factory="syncFactory">`. Here, please: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/transactions.html#transaction-synchronization

Comment: I updated my answer according fresh info

Comment: First of all your qiestion looks very bad. You should to show all info from a start. Now I see what's going on: your channel is **queue**, so http request will be processed by separate Thread and your transaction is commited successfully just when the message is placed to the queue. Change it to the direct channel and evrything will be OK. Please, make questions more informative - save our time!

Comment: I'm very sorry (for my bad english too), I post for the first time so I will do my best the next time. I thought the channel should be a PollableChannel. With a DirectChannel it's works. Thanks you very much for all !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you need to use this one: [DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/transaction/DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory.java)

And here is a snapshot how to configure it:

```
SourcePollingChannelAdapter adapter = new SourcePollingChannelAdapter();
    ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor syncProcessor =
            new ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor();
    syncProcessor.setBeanFactory(mock(BeanFactory.class));
    PollableChannel queueChannel = new QueueChannel();
    syncProcessor.setBeforeCommitExpression(new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("#bix"));
    syncProcessor.setBeforeCommitChannel(queueChannel);
    syncProcessor.setAfterCommitChannel(queueChannel);
    syncProcessor.setAfterCommitExpression(new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("#baz"));

    DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory syncFactory =
            new DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory(syncProcessor);

    adapter.setTransactionSynchronizationFactory(syncFactory);
```

Transaction boundaries are covered in the `SourcePollingChannelAdapter#adviceChain`, so it should be configure like this:

```
    TransactionInterceptor txAdvice = 
    new TransactionInterceptor(transactionManager, 
         new MatchAlwaysTransactionAttributeSource(new DefaultTransactionAttribute()));
    adapter.setAdviceChain(Collections.singletonList(txAdvice));
```

So, now each 'poll' will be wrapped with transaction and your `syncFactory` will do the stuff.