# Spring Integration: Persistent and transactional QueueChannel

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

In Spring Integration we have a **Setup** that looks something like this:

```
                                                     ---> 
                                                     ---> 
(dispatcher) Messages --> Gateway ----> QueueChannel ---> MessageHandler (worker)
                                                     ---> 
                                                     --->
```

So we have one Dispatcher Thread that takes Messages from a MQTT-Broker and forwards them into the Queue. The Poller for the Queue is provided with a TaskExecuter, so the Consumer is multithreaded. 
We managed to implement all the functionalities. So the just described setup is already implemented.

Now **to guarantee no data loss** we want to make two things:

**1.:**
We want our queue to persist the data, so when the Programm shuts down ungracefully, all the data in the queue will still be there.
This also worked for us, we are using MongoDB as a database because we read somewhere in your docs that this is the recommended way to do it.

**2.:**
The second thing we want to assure is that the worker threads are working transactional. So only if the worker threads return correctly the messages will permanently be deleted from the queue (and therefore the persistent MessageStore). If the program shuts down during the processing of a message (by the worker thread) the message will still be in the queue at the next startup.
Also if the worker, for example, thows an exception during the processing of the message, it will be put back into the queue.

**Our implementation:**

As explained before, the basic setup of the program is already implemented. We then extended the basic implementation with a message store implementation for the queue.

*QueueChannel:*

```
@Bean
public PollableChannel inputChannel(BasicMessageGroupStore mongoDbChannelMessageStore) {
    return new QueueChannel(new MessageGroupQueue(mongoDbChannelMessageStore, "inputChannel"));
}
```

*backed by a Messagestore:*

```
@Bean
public BasicMessageGroupStore mongoDbChannelMessageStore(MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory) {
    MongoDbChannelMessageStore store = new MongoDbChannelMessageStore(mongoDbFactory);
    store.setPriorityEnabled(true);
    return store;
}
```

*the matching Poller*:

```
@Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
public PollerMetadata poller() {
    PollerMetadata poll = Pollers.fixedDelay(10).get(); 
    poll.setTaskExecutor(consumer);
    return poll;
}
```

*Executor*:

```
private Executor consumer = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
```

**What we have tried?**
As explained now we want to extend this implementation with a transactional functionality. We tried using the setTransactionSynchronizationFactory like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19423160/sourcepollingchanneladapter-with-transaction) but it wasn't working (didn't get errors or anything but the behavior was still as it was before we added the TransactionSynchronizer):

```
@Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
public PollerMetadata poller() {
    PollerMetadata poll = Pollers.fixedDelay(10).get(); 
    poll.setTaskExecutor(consumer);

    BeanFactory factory = mock(BeanFactory.class);
    ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor etsp = new ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor();
    etsp.setBeanFactory(factory);
    etsp.setAfterRollbackChannel(inputChannel());
    etsp.setAfterRollbackExpression(new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("#bix"));
    etsp.setAfterCommitChannel(inputChannel());
    etsp.setAfterCommitExpression(new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("#bix"));
    DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory dtsf = new DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory(etsp);

    poll.setTransactionSynchronizationFactory(dtsf);

    return poll;
}
```

What would be the best way to realize our requirements in spring integration?

**EDIT:**
As recommended in the answer I chose to do this with the JdbcChannelMessageStore. So I tried converting the XML Implementation described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-message-store) (18.4.2) into Java.  I wasn't quite sure on how to do it, this is what I have tried so far:

I created H2 database and run the script shown [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-jdbc/src/main/resources/org/springframework/integration/jdbc/schema-h2.sql) on it.

Created JDBCChannelMessageStore Bean:

```
@Bean
public JdbcChannelMessageStore store() {
    JdbcChannelMessageStore ms =  new JdbcChannelMessageStore();
    ms.setChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider(queryProvider());
    ms.setUsingIdCache(true);
    ms.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return ms;
}
```

Created H2ChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider

```
    @Bean
    public ChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider queryProvider() {
        return new H2ChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider();
    }
```

Adapted the poller:

```
@Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
public PollerMetadata poller() throws Exception {
    PollerMetadata poll = Pollers.fixedDelay(10).get();
    poll.setTaskExecutor(consumer);
    poll.setAdviceChain(Collections.singletonList(transactionInterceptor()));

    return poll;
}
```

Autowired my PlaatformTransactionManager:

```
@Autowired
PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
```

And created TransactionInterceptor from the TransactonManager:

```
@Bean
public TransactionInterceptor transactionInterceptor() {
    return new TransactionInterceptorBuilder(true)
                .transactionManager(transactionManager)
                .isolation(Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
                .propagation(Propagation.REQUIRED)
                .build();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to have queue as transactional, you definitely should take a look into the transactional `MessageStore`. And only JDBC one is like that. Just because only JDBC support transactions. So, when we perform `DELETE`, it is OK only if TX is committed.

The MongoDB, nor any other NoSQL DataBases, support such a model, therefore you only can push back the failed messages to the DB on rollback using `TransactionSynchronizationFactory`.

**UPDATE**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext
public class So47264688Tests {

    private static final String MESSAGE_GROUP = "transactionalQueueChannel";

    private static EmbeddedDatabase dataSource;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() {
        dataSource = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .addScript("classpath:/org/springframework/integration/jdbc/schema-drop-h2.sql")
                .addScript("classpath:/org/springframework/integration/jdbc/schema-h2.sql")
                .build();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void destroy() {
        dataSource.shutdown();
    }

    @Autowired
    private PollableChannel transactionalQueueChannel;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcChannelMessageStore jdbcChannelMessageStore;

    @Autowired
    private PollingConsumer serviceActivatorEndpoint;

    @Autowired
    private CountDownLatch exceptionLatch;

    @Test
    public void testTransactionalQueueChannel() throws InterruptedException {
        GenericMessage<String> message = new GenericMessage<>("foo");
        this.transactionalQueueChannel.send(message);

        assertTrue(this.exceptionLatch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        this.serviceActivatorEndpoint.stop();

        assertEquals(1, this.jdbcChannelMessageStore.messageGroupSize(MESSAGE_GROUP));
        Message<?> messageFromStore = this.jdbcChannelMessageStore.pollMessageFromGroup(MESSAGE_GROUP);

        assertNotNull(messageFromStore);
        assertEquals(message, messageFromStore);
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableIntegration
    public static class ContextConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
            return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
        }

        @Bean
        public ChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider queryProvider() {
            return new H2ChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider();
        }

        @Bean
        public JdbcChannelMessageStore jdbcChannelMessageStore() {
            JdbcChannelMessageStore jdbcChannelMessageStore = new JdbcChannelMessageStore(dataSource);
            jdbcChannelMessageStore.setChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider(queryProvider());
            return jdbcChannelMessageStore;
        }

        @Bean
        public PollableChannel transactionalQueueChannel() {
            return new QueueChannel(new MessageGroupQueue(jdbcChannelMessageStore(), MESSAGE_GROUP));
        }

        @Bean
        public TransactionInterceptor transactionInterceptor() {
            return new TransactionInterceptorBuilder()
                    .transactionManager(transactionManager())
                    .isolation(Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
                    .propagation(Propagation.REQUIRED)
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        public TaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
            ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
            threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(5);
            return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
        }

        @Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
        public PollerMetadata poller() {
            return Pollers.fixedDelay(10)
                    .advice(transactionInterceptor())
                    .taskExecutor(threadPoolTaskExecutor())
                    .get();
        }

        @Bean
        public CountDownLatch exceptionLatch() {
            return new CountDownLatch(2);
        }

        @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "transactionalQueueChannel")
        public void handle(Message<?> message) {
            System.out.println(message);
            try {
                throw new RuntimeException("Intentional for rollback");
            }
            finally {
                exceptionLatch().countDown();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I looked into the JdbcChannelMessageStore. I was trying to rewrite the JdbcChannelMessageStore implementation explained here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-message-store at 18.4.2 into java. But I had no success with it. I edited my original post to show what I was trying to do.

Comment: What you do with the `JdbcChannelMessageStore` is correct. Now you need to configure your `PollerMetadata` with the `TransactionInterceptor` into its `setAdviceChain`. You don't need `TransactionSynchronizationFactory` at all. (At the same time I hope you configure that `QueueChannel` to use this `JdbcChannelMessageStore`)

Comment: Persistence of queue is working, but I still have Troubles with my transactions. I am trying to throw new RuntimeException(); in my Worker, but the transaction is not rolled back(Message is not put back into queue, but lost). To see what I have changed, I edited my post again. (Adapted Poller and added TransactionInterceptor)

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer. I fully followed with your explanations and it works for me well. I see rollbacks and message isn't lost from the JDBC store. Cheers!

Comment: Your implementation works for me but I cant get it to run in my usecase. Why do you call this.serviceActivatorEndpoint.stop(); ?

Comment: To stop polling message from the queue consistently and always get a rollback

Comment: I again ran your tests. assertEquals(message, messageFromStore); does return assertionError: 
message: GenericMessage `[payload=foo, headers={id=cd74d47c-101c-8c6e-799c-1bd9a95ce71b, timestamp=1510782912512}]`

messageFromStoreGenericMessage `[payload=foo, headers={JdbcChannelMessageStore.CREATED_DATE=1510782912513, id=cd74d47c-101c-8c6e-799c-1bd9a95ce71b, JdbcChannelMessageStore.SAVED=true, timestamp=1510782912533}]`

I'm not sure if thats the problem I'm having. I posted my implementation on pastebin:
[link](https://pastebin.com/PRhD4n3S)

Comment: Ha! You use Spring Integration < 5.0. We have fixed those extra header for JDBC recently. But anyway our purpose to see that message stays in the store after rollback.

Comment: Thanks. In debugging I now saw that in my implementation, in Field ServiceActivator -> adviceChain -> transactionInterceptor -> transactionManager is null, could this be my Problem?

Comment: No, that’s not related. The desired advice is in the `PollingConsumer` endpoint

Comment: Sorry I meant to write PollingConsumer. So the TransactionManager in PollingConsumer is null for me.

Comment: Oh! Really? Try to use then `PollerMetadata` directly instead of `Pollers` factory. I’ll check your cod tomorrow with the Spring Integration 4.3

Comment: Works for me well. You really have to wait for the `latch` in your code to ensure that transactional handle has happened. But you can't do that from the `onApplicationEvent()`. That's too early. Plus I used `@Qualifier("transactionalQueueChannel")` for the `PollableChannel transactionalQueueChannel` `@Autowired` in your code. And yes, it is with the Spring Integration `4.3`. Maybe you can really share with me that simple Spring Boot app with the instruction how to reproduce? Otherwise I don't know how else to help you

Comment: Thanks for support. I think I found the problem. I will post the solution here if I'm 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Artem Bilan for your great support. I finally found the solution. It seemed like there was another bean with the name transactionManager and transactionInterceptor active. This resulted in the strange behavior, that my trans-manager was never initialized, instead the other transactionmanager (null) was used for the transactioninterceptor and the PollingConsumer. Thats why my Transactionmanager in PollingConsumer was null, and why my Transactions were never working.

The solution was to rename all my beans, for some beans I also used the annotation @Primary to tell spring to always use this speciffic bean when autowired.

I also downgraded two 4.3, just to make sure this wasn't an error related to Version 5. I haven't testet if it would work with V 5 yet,  but I think it should work also.