# Spring Integration Jdbc ChannelMessageStore Repoll Failed Message

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Followed the guidance as mentioned in [Spring Integration: Persistent and transactional QueueChannel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47264688/spring-integration-persistent-and-transactional-queuechannel) and implemented the `Jdbc ChannelMessageStore`. Got it to working except for the below,

1. `Poller` should pick the failed messages for retry. Failed messages are picked only after a restart
2. Max retries to discard the message even if transaction fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, with transaction is does that by default: the failed message is not deleted from DB and the next poll should pick it up. I'd be glad to investigate if that is otherwise, but I probably need a simple sample from you. There is no way to have retry attempts on those messages since we work in transaction and therefore rolled back message is just remained in DB as it was before transaction: we cannot modify it. There is a `maxAttempts` option on a `DelayHandler`, but that's fully different story.

Comment: Thanks Artem, I shall share a sample project soon.

Comment: The sample project created https://github.com/syedyusufh/jdbc-channelmessagestore works fine :( Only difference is Postgres and `Jms.outboundAdapter` in the actual application. Is there any logs that I could share to help understand the behavior in Postgres and JmsHandler? Thanks

Comment: OK. So, you use that `setUsingIdCache(true)`. So, consider to remove it altogether or follow its Docs recommendations: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/jdbc.html#concurrent-polling. There is already `LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE` hint applied to Postgres queries.

Comment: That fixed the issue, but wondering why should it be an issue as PostgreSQL supports MVCC.

Comment: Sorry, not fully clear what you mean. I said that `setUsingIdCache(true)` caused your problem with rolled back messages not being retried again until you restart. That option stores message ids in a `Map` and of course it clear on restart. So, you made the trap yourself. The option clearly recommend to synchronize with TX to remove just rolled back entry from the cache. Of course we don't need this option in most cases. Therefore it is `false` by default.

Comment: Thanks Artem for the detailed explanation.