# spring integration redis poller with transaction

Tags: redis, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

i use spring integeration redis,poll message from redis, like this:

```
@Bean
public PseudoTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    final PseudoTransactionManager pseudoTransactionManager = new PseudoTransactionManager();
    return pseudoTransactionManager;
}

@Bean
public TransactionSynchronizationFactory transactionSynchronizationFactory() {
    ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor transactionSynchronizationProcessor = new ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor();
    transactionSynchronizationProcessor.setAfterCommitExpression(this.PARSER.parseExpression("#store.rename('commit')"));
    transactionSynchronizationProcessor.setAfterRollbackExpression(this.PARSER.parseExpression("#store.rename('roll')"));
    DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory transactionSynchronizationFactory = new DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory(transactionSynchronizationProcessor);
    return transactionSynchronizationFactory;
}


@Bean
public SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean sourcePollingChannelAdapter(RedisStoreMessageSource redisStoreMessageSource, TransactionSynchronizationFactory transactionSynchronizationFactory) {

    SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean sourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean = new SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean();
    sourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean.setAutoStartup(true);
    sourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean.setOutputChannelName("mail-delivery-status-route-channel");
    sourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean.setSource(redisStoreMessageSource);
    PollerMetadata pollerMetadata = new PollerMetadata();
    pollerMetadata.setMaxMessagesPerPoll(10);
    pollerMetadata.setTransactionSynchronizationFactory(transactionSynchronizationFactory);
    PeriodicTrigger periodicTrigger = new PeriodicTrigger(2000);
    pollerMetadata.setTrigger(periodicTrigger);
    sourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean.setPollerMetadata(pollerMetadata);


    return sourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean;
}


@Bean
public TestHandler testHandler() {

    return new TestHandler();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow trans() {
    return flow -> flow.channel("mail-delivery-status-route-channel").handle(testHandler());
}
```

Normally, after the process is complete, the afterCommit `#store.rename('commit')` operation will be performed, but it is not doing it now, and will continue polling , i debug ,find that:  `AbstractPollingEndpoint#bindResourceHolderIfNecessary` `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()` is always false.
How can I improve the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pollerMetadata.setTransactionSynchronizationFactory(transactionSynchronizationFactory);` is not enough. You are missing to add an `adviceChain` into the `PollerMetadata`, where one of them should be `TransactionInterceptor`. See `TransactionInterceptorBuilder` for convenience.

Although it's fully unclear why would one use `SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean` manually if there is a Java DSL already in the project and the `IntegrationFlow` can handle all the boilerplate code for you. I mean you need to look into the:

```
/**
 * Populate the provided {@link MessageSource} object to the {@link IntegrationFlowBuilder} chain.
 * The {@link org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow} {@code startMessageSource}.
 * In addition use {@link SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec} to provide options for the underlying
 * {@link org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter} endpoint.
 * @param messageSource the {@link MessageSource} to populate.
 * @param endpointConfigurer the {@link Consumer} to provide more options for the
 * {@link org.springframework.integration.config.SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean}.
 * @return new {@link IntegrationFlowBuilder}.
 * @see MessageSource
 * @see SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec
 */
public static IntegrationFlowBuilder from(MessageSource<?> messageSource,
        Consumer<SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec> endpointConfigurer) {
```

And configure `.transactional()` and `transactionSynchronizationFactory()` there on the `PollerSpec`.

Comment: thanks，after adding the adviceChain ，the code is ok ，and can refer to
 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19423160/sourcepollingchanneladapter-with-transaction'